# If/else with an area for echo's

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

So Im having a bit of a conundrum. Not too sure how I should go about doing the if/else statements with an Echo at the top with the answers, with bullets.

```
 <?php
    echo 
    ?>
    </p>
<p>
  A Chicken
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" value="no">
  <label for="radio3">Choose this answer</label>
</p>
<p dir="ltr">A Ear of Corn.
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" value="no">
          <label for="radio2">Choose this answer</label>
</p>
        <p dir="ltr"> A Heart. 
          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="yes"> Choose this answer
        </p>


 <p dir="ltr">
          <input type="button" name="button28" id="button28" value="Yes! That is the answer I chose!">
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: You don't use `echo` when you're displaying literal HTML with `?>`. Either remove `echo` or use a here-doc.

Comment: Where are you trying to put `if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is basically about how to output certain HTML code based on an if/else clause, then with such a lengthy amount of HTML code as you have posted you would do much better using HEREDOCS checkout the PHP manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on many ways. Here is a small example to get you started working with forms.

```
<?php

    $answer = '';

    if(isset($_POST['send'])            //check if the form has been sent
       && isset($_POST['answer'])){     //check if an answer is filled in


        //You could also use a switch -> http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php
        if($_POST['answer'] == 'chicken'){      //check if post variable answer value = chicken

            $answer = 'your answer is "a chicken"';

        }elseif($_POST['answer'] == 'corn'){    //check if post variable answer value= corn

            $answer = 'your answer is "A Ear of Corn."';

        }elseif($_POST['answer'] == 'heart'){   //check if post variable answer value = heart

            $answer = 'your answer is "A Heart"';

        }

        //echo the variable.
        echo $answer;

    }

?>


<form method="POST" action="">
    <p> A Chicken
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio3" value="chicken">
        <label for="radio3">Choose this answer</label>
    </p>
    <p dir="ltr">A Ear of Corn.
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio2" value="corn">
        <label for="radio2">Choose this answer</label>
    </p>
    <p dir="ltr">A Heart.
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio" value="heart">Choose this answer
    </p>

    <input type="submit" name="send" id="button28" value="Yes! That is the answer I chose!">

</form>
```